# Conflicting template definitions and ODR

Tags: c++, templates, linker, language-lawyer, one-definition-rule

Imagine a situation where I have two distinct translation units a.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

double bar();

template <typename T>
T foobar(T t) {
    return t;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "foobar called from b.cpp: " << bar() << '\n';
    std::cout << "foobar called from a.cpp: " << foobar(1.) << '\n';
}
```

and b.cpp:

```
template <typename T>
T foobar(T t) {
    return t + 1.;
}

double bar() {
    return foobar(1.);
}
```

I know that for templates, there are exceptions to the ODR, i.e. the compiler will mark instantiated function templates as such and will strike out all but one during the linking process. I noticed that the compiler doesn't actually care whether the generated codes of such instantiations at different translation units are actually identical or at least equivalent.

In the code above, this is the case. When compiling, linking and running with

```
c++ a.cpp b.cpp -o result -std=c++17 && ./result
```

it will yield the result

```
foobar called from b.cpp: 1
foobar called from a.cpp: 1
```

So apparently, the instantiation inside the object file b.o got thrown away in favour for that one from a.o. When compiling and linking with b.cpp and a.cpp swapped, like

```
c++ b.cpp a.cpp -o result -std=c++17 && ./result
```

the result will be

```
foobar called from b.cpp: 2
foobar called from a.cpp: 2
```

so the exact opposite happens: the instantiation that got mentioned first in the list of to-be-linked object files will be the one that survives. Is such a behaviour defined somewhere within the standard? Depending on the build system, the order in which the object files are mentioned can be rather arbitrary, but, as in such examples it leads to very different programs and possibly cumbersome bugs. Even if I try to explicitely instantiate the version from a.cpp by adding

```
template double foobar<double>(double);
```

it will not make the foobar<> template from a.cpp survive when mentioning b.o before a.o in the linker list.

Comment: just out of curiousity: is this a purely academic question, or do you have a real case where this is an issue? I mean you could define the template only once and the problem is gone.

Comment: It looks like you want to add the tag [tag:language-lawyer] to your question!?

Comment: @WernerHenze that answers my question ;)

Comment: My question is of academic origin but I think you can run into this problem quite easily. When working on a large code base (here represented by a.cpp), adding a new translation unit b.cpp with just a local helper template which I do not intend to be visible outside of b.cpp, the function bar() will call a completely different foobar() function from that one that I defined in the very same file if it got defined at the same scope somewhere else (here a.cpp). The fact that there is no warning there worries me a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I know that for templates, there are exceptions to the ODR

There are no exceptions for ODR for template, it is just that template functions are `inline`.

And your program has ODR violation.
You would have similar issue with regular inline functions.

Comment: I can reproduce that. I was not aware that you apparently can violate ODR and run so easily into UB without the linker producing any error or warning, basically by just adding an inline or template function definition.