# Why does not c++ template generate duplicate symbols when it is included by mutiple source files?

Tags: c++, templates, one-definition-rule

I would like to know why a template instantiated function in two independent object files does not result in a symbol duplication when linking together. I am running a clang version 11.0.0 compiler on MacOS.

For example, I have a template function defined in a C++ header file, `template.h`, like this:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void print(T msg)
{
    std::cout << "From Template print:" << msg << "\n";
}
```

Then I have two source files, `a.cpp` and `b.cpp`, include this header file, like:

`a.cpp:`

```
#include "template.h"
#include <string>

void a_func(const std::string& s)
{
    print("a::" + s);
    return;
}
```

`b.cpp:`

```
#include "template.h"
#include <string>

void b_func(const std::string& s)
{
    print("b::" + s);
    return;
}
```

Then I compile both cpp files *independently*, like:

```
c++ -o a.o -c a.cpp
c++ -o b.o -c b.cpp
```

My understanding of the template instantiation is, since the `a_func()` called the `print<>()` with a `string` type argument, the compiler generated a function with a signature like `void print(string)`, in the object file `a.o`. Then the compiler did the same thing to the object file `b.o`. So the same symbol `void print(string)` was defined in both `a.o` and `b.o`.

So now I have a main program to bring both object files together, like:

```
#include <string>

extern void a_func(const std::string& s);
extern void b_func(const std::string& s);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    a_func("Call from MAIN to A");
    b_func("Call from MAIN to B");
    return 0;
}
```

Then compile and link them together:

```
c++ -o main.o -c main.cpp
c++ -o main main.o a.o b.o
```

I expected it *won't* compile, but it did. I thought the same symbol, `void print(string)` was defined twice in both `a.o` and `b.o`. When they were linked with `main.o`, the linker would see the duplicated symbol and complain. However this is not the case, so my understanding must be incorrect. I like to know why the linker does not treat the template instantiated functions in two object files as duplicated.

The `objdump` showed both object files had the same `void print(string)` symbol:

```
$ objdump -t a.o  |grep print
0000000000000080 gw    F __TEXT,__text  __Z5printINSt3__112basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEEEvT_
$ objdump -t b.o  |grep print
0000000000000080 gw    F __TEXT,__text  __Z5printINSt3__112basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEEEvT_
```

If I manually define a function in the `template.h`, and include it to both `a.cpp` and `b.cpp`, like:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void print(T msg)
{
    std::cout << "From Template print:" << msg << "\n";
}

void samefunc(void)
{
    return;
}
```

The linker complained the duplicated symbol as expected:

```
c++ -o main.o -c main.cpp
c++ -o a.o -c a.cpp
c++ -o b.o -c b.cpp
c++ -o main main.o a.o b.o
duplicate symbol 'samefunc()' in:
    a.o
    b.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Why it is different from the template instantiated version?

Comment: template functions behave as their were marked [`inline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline), so no duplicated symbols.

Comment: Not the same question, but answers the question: [Conflicting template definitions and ODR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46340305/conflicting-template-definitions-and-odr)

Comment: A simple answer would be "because it would be awfully impractical", although that's a bit of a weasel tactic: there are lots of C and C++ "features" that would be rightfully called awfully impractical by a large chunk of the userbase yet here we are...